# Make button under image clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to code a little 'card' that has an image, which when you hover in, it fades the image out and shows up a button which I'm trying to make clickable. The problem is that the button cannot be clicked since it's under the image and when you click on it, it registers as a click on the image. I know I could make it so the user can just click the image, but that doesn't work well on mobile since you cannot hover without clicking.

Here's my HTML: (note: this is a basic version of my actual cards)

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

img.rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 30, 40, 1);
}

.btn btn-primary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.card {
  //background: #1D1E28;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.card img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="height: 18rem; width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/black-discord-icon/black-discord-icon-19.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-corners guildimg" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body" style="height: 172px;">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg manage-btn" target="_blank" role="button">Manage server</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"it registers as a click on the button"_ I think you meant to say here as a click on the image but not the button

Comment: @j08691 oh yeah! sorry about that! was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution what i see might be if *hover* handler will be on the `.card:hover img` not the `.card img:hover`. And remove form the image event with `pointer-events: none;`

```
.card:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  console.log('click');
  ev.target.textContent = 'cliked';
});
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

img.rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 30, 40, 1);
}

.btn btn-primary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.card {
  background: #1d1e28;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="height: 18rem; width: 18rem">
  <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/black-discord-icon/black-discord-icon-19.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-corners guildimg" alt="..." />
  <div class="card-body" style="height: 172px"></div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg manage-btn" target="_blank" role="button">
          Manage server
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```